# Accessing a node from MongoDB Atlass account with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

i am a novis with pymongo,a MongoDB driver. I created a mongodb atlas account, created a mongodb client. when try to access the primary node with client.primary, i get the address the the primary node.Please could someone help me on how to get the node itself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i mean.
client = pymongo.MongoClient('ulr')
client.nodes
The statement print(client.nodes) gives the addresses of the nodes. But i wish to get the nodes themselves so that i can distinguish which is healty and which is not healthy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it would be great that if you can format your answer a bit, to make it clearer. For example format the codes block.